# Why isn't boost::filesystem header only?

Tags: boost, boost-filesystem

Out of intellectual curiosity, I was wondering why the boost::filesystem library had a compiled component, while in other cases no compiled components are necessary. What is in the compiled portion that can not be in a hpp?

What really confuses me is that on my computer I compile this portion anyway (before using the library), and I would thus expect it to be possible or even preferred to perform the same compilation I did in BJam every time I build my application.

Why is there the additional *.so/*.a file?

Comment: I don't understand the second part. Why would it be preferable to build something over and over again when you can build it once?

Comment: Building it over and over again from the *.hpp file is something that happens with most parts of the boost library. This is how C++ code is usually compiled? In the case of Boost::Filesystem this is an additional .so/.a file. This is not the case for other parts of boost such as Boost::format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some boost libraries are header-only and some other need to be built (system, filesystem, graph, mpi, serialization, etc); several boost libraries can be configured to be either header-only or separately built.

The advantages of separately built libs are quite obvious: your own project compiles faster and depends on less external code.

However, build complexity is the tradeoff.

Comment: both boost.system (since 1.69) and boost.graph (since always since it's pretty much only templates) are header only